# adding cluster to a federation - apiserver authentication with certificate

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed a federaton control plane to a host cluster this is kubeconfig of the host cluster :

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
    server: https://k8s-apiserver.bcmt.cluster.local:8443
  name: bcmt-kubernetes
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://172.16.1.4:32471
  name: federation
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: bcmt-kubernetes
    namespace: default
    user: kubectl
  name: default-context
- context:
    cluster: federation
    user: federation
  name: federation
- context:
    cluster: bcmt-kubernetes
    namespace: kube-system
    user: kubectl
  name: kube-system-context
current-context: default-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: federation
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
    token: e7506989-42eb-11e8-bf70-fa163eb593a3
- name: federation-basic-auth
  user:
    password: e7506937-42eb-11e8-bf70-fa163eb593a3
    username: admin
- name: kubectl
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubectl.pem
    client-key: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubectl-key.pem
```

and now i'm trying to join a cluster to the federation, below the configuration of this cluster :

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
    server: https://k8s-apiserver.bcmt.cluster.local:8443
  name: bcmt-kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: bcmt-kubernetes
    namespace: default
    user: kubectl
  name: default-context
- context:
    cluster: bcmt-kubernetes
    namespace: kube-system
    user: kubectl
  name: kube-system-context
current-context: default-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubectl
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubectl.pem
    client-key: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubectl-key.pem
```

As you can see the acces to the api server is done with certificate how to do in order to join this cluster to federation; I mean should i expose the apiserver of the cluster that i'm joining  and how the host cluster will use the certificate in order to reach the apiserver of the joining cluster ? 
Any hints please how to do that !